# How to Make Function Return Generic Value in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics

I have an abstract class in VB.NET. I want all classes that inherit from this class to return whatever value makes sense. For example, it could be an Decimal, Integer, String. How can I delcare the function in the abstract base class to allow for this? Is this even possible?

Right now, my abstract class looks like this:

```
Public MustInherit Class ConversionBaseClass

    Public MustOverride Function GetConvertedObject()

End Class
```

I know its return value needs modified, but im not sure as to what. Something like this maybe?

```
Public MustOverride Function GetConvertedObject() Of (T)
```

Comment: Will your inherited classes always return the same type (per inherited class) eg BoolConversion always returns bool?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the Base class be generic of T then you can use it for the method

```
Public MustInherit Class ConversionBaseClass (Of T) 

    Public MustOverride Function GetConvertedObject() As T

End Class
```

Then you define your inheriting classes like

```
public Class IntConversion Inherits ConversionBaseClass(Of Integer) 

   Public Overrides Function GetConvertedObject() As Integer
```

Comment: Did you intend for it to be a "pubic" class?

Comment: Growl, my keyboard always does that to be, it's worse when I use a variable called "count"!

Comment: If you will be converting to inheritable class types, I would suggest using an interface `IConversionInterface(Of Out T)` rather than an abstract class.  If you do so, then an implementation of `IConversionInterface(Of FordMustangConvertible)` will be usable as an `IConversionInterface(Of Vehicle)`.

Answer (score 5):

```
Public MustOverride Function GetConvertedObject(Of T)() As T
```

should do it.